# VS2015 error C2362 instead of warning C4533

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, clang

This is not compiling on VS2015, but compiles on clang:

```
struct X
{
    X(){}
    ~X(){}
};

int main() {
    goto L;
    X x;
L:
    return 0;
}
```

error C2362: initialization of 'x' is skipped by 'goto L'.

Only when X contains a ctor+dtor or virtual dtor it's not compiling on VS2015.
Is there any way to suppress this error?
Why clang is supporting Microsoft feature in wider range than VS?

Comment: You are compiling with `/Za` which enforces the standard.  The example MS gives uses in `int`.  See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6s80d9f.aspx  g++ 5.1.0 also report an error, suggest you increase the warning/error level of your clang compile.

Comment: [I get the same error with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6fc844bfa810425)

Comment: @RichardCritten I do not use `/Za`, for MS example it's working. Try by your own.

Comment: @Borgleader Try without `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, then it compiles.

Comment: @RichardCritten The thing is that I want to compile this.

Comment: @GrzegorzTerlikowski, First, `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` are for warnings, not errors, and it gives an error. That said, I removed them myself and got the same error. [Even Clang 3.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Sj3yKo6UQpJ5UV1T) gives this error.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  `goto` is normally (almost never) not required in C++ and can be eliminated with proper factoring of your code.

Comment: @GrzegorzTerlikowski [I did](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c0437effc9504c9), still doesn't compile.

Comment: @Borgleader Try `-target x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`, then it shows `warning: jump from this goto statement to its label is a Microsoft extension [-Wmicrosoft-goto]`, but compiles (on your env it's not linking, because it's linux env)

Comment: The standard says you can only a _" trivial default constructors"_ you have a user supplied one.  If you remove it the error goes away,